# Input file name in Spark 1.6.0 View

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I cannot use the `input_file_name()` function in Spark 1.6.0 views. It works in select statements or in `df.withColumn("path", input_file_name())`, but not in a view.

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW v_test AS SELECT *, input_file_name() FROM table
```

fails. It also fails when i use `INPUT__FILE__NAME` instead. Just:

```
SELECT *, input_file_name() FROM table
```

works as expected. Is this a known bug or am i doing something wrong?
PS: I can create the view in Hive, but cannot access it from Spark as it fails with the same error: unknown function...

**UPDATE:**
I use Zeppelin with livy interpreter and Scala API.
The error i get from the above query to create the view is:
`invalid function input_file_name`
I also tried to import the function, but it has no effect

Comment: I use scala... but what you say is, it only works from Spark 2.0 upwards?

Comment: it works for me . :) can you update with what you tried?

Comment: I have answered below on how to create a temp view :) hope it helps to solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you think this could be an issue with livy?

Comment: Another thing, shouldn't `INPUT__FILE__NAME` work since i use the `HiveContext`?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have `create a temp view` as below

```
df.registerTempTable("table")
```

and then use `input_file_name()`. It would just work perfect.

```
sqlContext.sql("select *, input_file_name() from table")
```

for *newer versions of spark* you can use following api for *creating temp* view

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I want to create the view permanently and then use from many spark applications. The thing is, I can create the view in Hive, but when i then query it from Zeppelin with Spark I get the error

Comment: I have no idea about that. You should update that information in the question. somebody will surely answer yours